# How to host a Light Table server?

Tags: ide, web-hosting, lighttable

Does anyone know if it is possible to host Light Table on a own server, and how to do this ?

It is an awesome IDE and it would be even more awesome if I can run it on a development server, allowing my teams to code in browser with Light Table :-)